# Electric Potential-can anyone give the concept behind this?

Tags: electrostatics, potential

Three points A, B and C lie in a uniform electric field (E) of 5 x 103 NC-1 as shown in the figure. Find the potential difference between A and C.

[image]

I think there is some trick?

How can the pd across AC is equal to pd across AB?

Answer (score 4):

> I think there is some trick?

The electric field is horizontal thus the electric potential varies in the horizontal direction only, not the vertical direction.

I wouldn't call this a trick but it does appear that the question tests your conceptual grasp of the relationship between the electric field and electric potential.

In particular, you should be able to conclude by inspection that vertical lines are equipotential lines, i.e., B & C have the same value of electric potential.